# How to repeat background image in Android

Tags: android, xml, image, background, repeat

I am trying to make an xml for a background of a layout. Here is the code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/text_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp"><bitmap android:src="@drawable/paper_texture" android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I am inflating the layout and set this xml as a background of it. The problem is that when I write the layout with xml, it works well but when I inflate it programatically the background image doesn't repeat, and fits the whole layout instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the background using the layout, the layout is inflating to the repeat mode because it knows the proper size to fill. When you inflate programmatically, the inflater does not know what height to inflate it to so you won't get the repeat mode. When you place the inflated view as background, it has no choice but to stretch. What you can try is to set the parentView when inflating.

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.customWrapper);
View view;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, ll);
```

This way the inflater know what height/width it needs to fill.

Hope this helps.